# Stop sound when mouse is clicked outside modal form in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a modal form which I want to close when the user clicks outside it (the form tries to mimick the behaviour of the drop down area of a combo box).

I can to that like so:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x86 && (int) m.WParam == 0)
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.None)
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

My problem is that a sound is played at the same time, and I'd like to stop that.

Comment: what sound? The default Windows sound? Nothing you can do about that really.

Comment: Yes the default windows sound. Of course there is something I can do about that. Just a question of how much work I need to put into my soulution.

Comment: I agree with @Ahmedilyas. Btw, you should declare `const int`s for the WinAPI constants for the sake of understanding what `0x86` stands for.

Comment: Remember, there is a reason why there is a sound setting for being played when the parent modal window is being clicked.... to alert the user that there is something attached to that parent window that is focused upon. you cannot really stop Windows from doing that - its a Windows behaviour.

Comment: Most Windows behaviour can be overridden. I can solve this by using a low level MouseHook, I want to avoid that clumsy solution if possible. Saying this it cannot be done is simply plain wrong! :-)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I too believe that if you handle proper windows messages, then anything is possible. It won't be easy enough but not impossible either,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. You need to mimic the drop down control. Then why not use the `ToolStripDropDown`?

If you're not aware of it, here it is. You can create `ToolStripDropDown` and show any custom control inside it using `ToolStripControlHost`.

It will automatically close when user clicks outside of it. You can also manually close it by calling  `ToolStripDropDown.Close`

A small example will look like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripDropDown dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();

    ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add("Item " + i);
    }

    listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, args) => dropDown.Close();

    dropDown.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(listBox));

    dropDown.Show(MousePosition);
}
```